# (newbie) Reddit.NET oauth not working cant seem to find the problem

Tags: c#, .net, reddit, reddit-access-token

library : https://github.com/sirkris/Reddit.NET

cant get oauth to work
this is the code :

```
 public class RedditManager
{
    private readonly RedditClient _redditClient;
    public RedditManager(string appID, string appSecret)
    {
        string refreshToken = AuthorizeUser(appID, appSecret);
        _redditClient = new RedditClient(appID, refreshToken, appSecret);
    }
        
    public static string AuthorizeUser(string appId, string appSecret = null, int port = 8080)
    {
        // Create a new instance of the auth token retrieval library.  --Kris
        AuthTokenRetrieverLib authTokenRetrieverLib = new AuthTokenRetrieverLib(appId, appSecret, port);

        // Start the callback listener.  --Kris
        // Note - Ignore the logging exception message if you see it.  You can use Console.Clear() after this call to get rid of it if you're running a console app.
        authTokenRetrieverLib.AwaitCallback();

        // Open the browser to the Reddit authentication page.  Once the user clicks "accept", Reddit will redirect the browser to localhost:8080, where AwaitCallback will take over.  --Kris
        OpenBrowser(authTokenRetrieverLib.AuthURL());

        // Replace this with whatever you want the app to do while it waits for the user to load the auth page and click Accept.  --Kris
        while (true) { }

        // Cleanup.  --Kris
        authTokenRetrieverLib.StopListening();

        return authTokenRetrieverLib.RefreshToken;
    }

    private static void OpenBrowser(string authUrl, string browserPath = @"C:\Program Files\BraveSoftware\Brave-Browser\Application\brave.exe")
    {
        try
        {
            ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(authUrl);
            Process.Start(processStartInfo);
        }
        catch (System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception)
        {
            // This typically occurs if the runtime doesn't know where your browser is.  Use BrowserPath for when this happens.  --Kris
            ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(browserPath)
            {
                Arguments = authUrl
            };
            Process.Start(processStartInfo);
        }
        }
    public Task HotPosts(string subreddit)
    {
        var posts = _redditClient.Subreddit(subreddit).Posts.Hot;
        List<Post> videoposts = new List<Post>();
        foreach (var post in posts)
        {
            if (post.Permalink.Contains(".mp4"))
            {
                videoposts.Add(post);
            }
        }
        foreach (var post in videoposts)
        {
           Console.WriteLine(post.Info());
        }
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }


}
```

i get this error in the console :

`2024-01-24 11:40:27 [INFO]  (uhttpsharp.HttpServer) Embedded uhttpserver started. 2024-01-24 11:40:37 [INFO]  (uhttpsharp.HttpClientHandler) Got Client 127.0.0.1:59132 2024-01-24 11:40:37 [INFO]  (uhttpsharp.HttpServer) Embedded uhttpserver stopped. 2024-01-24 11:40:37 [INFO]  (uhttpsharp.HttpClientHandler) 127.0.0.1:59132 : Got request /Reddit.NET/oauthRedirect 2024-01-24 11:40:37 [WARN]  (uhttpsharp.HttpClientHandler) Error while serving : 127.0.0.1:59132 System.MissingMethodException Method not found: 'RestSharp.IRestRequest RestSharp.RestRequest.AddHeader(System.String, System.String)'. at Reddit.AuthTokenRetriever.AuthTokenRetrieverLib.<>c__DisplayClass37_0.<AwaitCallback>b__0(IHttpContext context, Func`1 next)
at uhttpsharp.AnonymousHttpRequestHandler.Handle(IHttpContext context, Func`1 next) at uhttpsharp.RequestHandlersAggregateExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<Aggregate>b__0(IHttpContext context) at uhttpsharp.HttpClientHandler.<Process>d__11.MoveNext() 2024-01-24 11:40:37 [INFO]  (uhttpsharp.HttpClientHandler) Lost Client 127.0.0.1:59132`

im sure the app secret / id etc are correct i put http://localhost:8080/Reddit.NET/oauthRedirect
in the redirect link just like the official tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xlWhLyVgN2s

Comment: i was using the wrong project type

Comment: Please explain your solution in an answer. Also please fix the formatting.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

fix: the project type was wrong lol the code was working great after i changed it =>(.net to core)